# How do I connect Visual Studio for Mac OS to Azure Dev Ops/VSTS?

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-mac

I have a project in Azure Dev Ops that I need to connect to and I'm using Visual Studio for Mac.

Usually on the PC I can click Version Control or project and browse to it, and then sync.  However, I don't see that.

In addition when I look at the project in the website, I don't see any URL that I can use to paste into the repository config.

[VSTS config screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bA9v1.png)

Answer (score 8):

To connect Azure Devops Git repo with Visual Studio for MAC, you can follow below steps:

In VS for Mac -> Version Control -> Checkout -> enter the Azure Devops Git repo URL and specify target directory -> checkout.

- For Azure Devops Git repo URL, you can use either of following:

  - `https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_git/repo`
  - `https://username@dev.azure.com/account/project/_git/repo`
- For connecting credential, you can use [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=vsts) for Alternate credential.

Besides, you can also refer the document [Checkout an existing repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/set-up-git-repository#checkout-an-existing-repository).

Comment: doesnt work. without the user the "clone" option is disabled. with the user the path is invalid. I copied the path from visual studio on my pc

Answer (score 1):

If you navigate to repository you're willing to interact with there's 'Clone' button that gives you all the necessary information to clone the repository.

[image: VSTS - location of <code>Clone</code> button.]

This brings up pop up that gives you the URL for repo. Sadly, no option to clone in Visual Studio for Mac (you have to fill the form you found yourself) :/

[image: VSTS clone repository dialog.]

Answer (score -4):

Follow this steps to connect Azure Devops Git repo with Visual Studio for MAC:

1. Open or Create a new projeto on Visual Studio and open it.
2. Go to the Top Menu, Select Visual Studio -> Extensions
3. Select Gallery  and make sure the option All the repositories is set
4. Under Version Control select Team Foundation Version Control for TFS and Azure DevOps
5. On the right menu click Install

Once its installed you can find it on the top menu under Version Control -> TFS / Azure DevOps

Comment: Once installed, it says: We will support git repositories soon

Comment: This answer is useless. #4 does not exist.